# When listing faculty that I'm interested in, would it be a good idea to list faculty that are in a related department?

Tags: graduate-admissions

I am currently applying to a M.S. Statistics program and have an easy first choice (whom I will refer to as "A") for someone with whom I would like to work. At this particular university I am applying to, the statistics and math departments are separate. A has worked with a professor in the math department ("B") on a subject that I am interested in.

Would it be a good idea to list B on the list of faculty with whom I would be interested in working on my graduate school application?

Comment: why not ask A ?

Comment: @Neo - I'm very new to this process and just started this process yesterday. I'm not sure what sort of contact is appropriate with professors who are from a very well-ranked university, considering that my university is not very well-ranked and quite unknown.

Comment: @Neo - That is not to suggest that such professors are arrogant, but I may not be taken seriously.

Comment: I think that its highly unlikely that any sort of ernest email would hurt anyone's chances of getting into graduate school. Why would rank have anything to do with contacting anyone? This is their job.

Comment: @Neo - All right, thank you. I will send A a message. If anyone else has any advice, please comment/answer.

Comment: @Clarinetist I would also agree with sending the email to A. You could also email B to see his view. He may have already worked with MS Stat in the past, for example.

Comment: @Compass Can you please turn this into an answer so that I can vote it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would also agree with sending the email to A. You could also email B to see his view. He may have already worked with MS Stat in the past, for example.

Because the two subjects aren't that too far apart, you may likely also be able to work out something that is tailored specifically to you. I haven't met too many professors who like to shoot everything down, so it never hurts to try.

Comment: As an update (not that anyone cares): I have been accepted to this M.S. statistics program and have pursued working with A. When I do get to the point of working on a thesis, I may ask to pursue work with B.

Admittedly, I still have a lot of exploring to do, so working with A might not even happen should my research interests change.

Comment: @Clarinetist good luck!